# How can remove the <scheduled date> in the org agenda view quickly?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In the emacs org agenda view(today), I schedule some tasks with the `<scheduled date>`. But now I want to remove the `<scheduled date>` single task or mutli tasks together. (Don't want to schedule them to the other day).

Now I have to `<TAB>` each tasks, and delete the `<scheduled date>` line.

Is there any quick key (speed key?) to do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**tl;dr** : In the agenda, <kbd>m</kbd> on all these tasks, then <kbd>C-u B s</kbd>.

---

This called for quite a bit of searching, but org-mode **is** powerful.

According to [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Inserting-deadline_002fschedule.html),

> **C-c C-s**     (org-schedule)
>   When called with a prefix argument, remove the scheduling date from the entry.

[and, in the agenda](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html#Agenda-commands):

> **B**     (org-agenda-bulk-action)
>   Bulk action: act on all marked entries in the agenda.
>
> > **s**  Schedule all items to a new date.

So what you need to do is:

- In the agenda, **mark** all the items you want to remove the sheduled date from (with <kbd>m</kbd>, like in dired)
- <kbd>C-u</kbd> as the prefix argument to **remove** the scheduling.
- <kbd>B s</kbd> to run `org-schedule` as a **bulk action**.

And you're done ! Enjoy :·)

Answer (score 11):

#### Remove scheduled date for single item

In agenda view, Press <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> on task.

#### Remove schedule date for multiple items

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182398/3451554) by [Nikana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449460/nikana-reklawyks) works perfectly well.

In agenda view, Mark the tasks with <kbd>m</kbd> then <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>B-s</kbd>.